# Estimate the degree of a Taylor Polynomial using its Error Term

Tags: polynomials, taylor-expansion

In my 2nd year studying Maths at Uni and revising for a Numerical Analysis final exam. We're given 1 past paper but no solutions, and I can't answer this question:

Use the error term of a Taylor polynomial to estimate the degree of the Taylor polynomial which approximates cox for |x|<_PIE/4, with an error of no greater than 10^-5.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Do you have any expression for the error term of Taylor polynomials at hand? (They come in different flavours)

Comment: I didn't know this, and I don't. Do I have to go through lecture notes rather than using books then?

Answer (score 1):

Since
$$\cos x = 1-\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^4}{24}-\frac{x^6}{720}+\frac{x^8}{40320}-\dots$$
and $\pi/4$ is roughly $1$, it's obvious that the answer is $6$ ... although for best results we should think of this $6$th degree polynomial as $T_7$ rather than $T_6$. Using the $T_6$ error bound [is for dummies](http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/calculating-error-bounds-for-taylor-polynomials.html).
The popular [Lagrange form of the remainder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor%27s_theorem#Explicit_formulae_for_the_remainder) for $T_7$ bounds the error by
$$\max_{[-\pi/4,\pi/4]}|f^{(8)}| \frac{(\pi/4)^8}{40320}<0.0000036 $$